# Mocking response for GraphQL query resolver from ServiceObject to prevent API calls in the UnitTests

Tags: python, automated-tests, graphql, graphene-python

Let's assume that I have the following service object:

```
class Foo(object):
    def bar(self):
        return ['foo', 'bar']
```

And this is the schema:

```
import Foo

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    bar = graphene.List(lambda: graphene.String)

    def resolve_bar(self, info):
        return Foo().bar()
```

I am trying to test if the GraphQL Schema is correctly calling the method `bar` in its query resolver. So, we have this piece of code in the tests:

```
from MySchema import Query

class TestFooBar(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('Foo')
    def test_bar(self, mock_foo):
        mock_foo.return_value.bar.return_value = ['baz', 'qux']

        my_schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
        client = Client(self.my_schema)

        query = '''
            query {
                bar()
            }
        '''
        executed = self.client.execute(query)

       #some attributes that I want to assert
       assertTrue(mock_foo.called) # returns False
```

### Why I am using mocks?

In the original ServiceObject class it makes some API calls to another service, which is already tested in a isolated way. And in this case, I only want to test if the GraphQL query `bar` is calling a method which will return its supposed object.

### The problem

When I mock the response that the service object returns as in the above code, and make the Graphene Client test runs the query, it gives me the 'non-mocked' response. In other words, *it is actually calling the original method provided by the service object class and making the API calls*, which **shouldn't be performed**. However, when I instantiate and run the ServiceObject class itself, it is correctly mocked and returns the `['baz', 'qux']` array, not going through the API calls.

### Do someone have an ideia of what I am doing wrong?

Or GraphQL Client responses shouldn't be mocked at all? Is there any approach that I can use instead of mocking it?

I already looked all over internet to see how people do that, but I couldn't manage to find any possible solutions.

Comment: It is possibly to write successful tests with graphene if you don't try to mock it -- for example see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45493295/testing-graphene-django/47762174#47762174

Comment: Hard to tell without a [mcve]. It might be that you are patching the wrong `Foo` or it might be that your production code doesn't do what you think it does. Getting `patch` right is quite hard, mocking is way easier if you use dependency injection. Besides you seem to be testing mostly third party code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## So, the problem is:

My `patch` is wrong. I should patch the callsite, not the definition site. In this case, it will be: `@patch('MySchema.Foo')` to accomplish the mocking of the callsite.

#### To prove that

```
from MySchema import Query

class TestFooBar(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('MySchema.Foo')
    def test_bar(self, mock_foo):
        mock_foo.return_value.bar.return_value = ['baz', 'qux']

        my_schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)
        client = Client(self.my_schema)

        query = '''
            query {
                bar()
            }
        '''
        executed = self.client.execute(query)

        assertTrue(mock_foo().bar.called) # now returns True
```

Thanks to **jkimbo** who came on the rescue when I asked in the [Graphene-Python Github repository](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/issues/896#issuecomment-456481084).

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question is about *Graphene*, but I had the same problem (mocking graphql resolver) with *Ariadne* and write this solution for others like me who have no access to enough documents about graphql unit tests with ariadne.

As said in the accepted answer, mocking resolver is not enough and graphql still calls the not mocked resolver. So we must change schema to call this new function instead of main resolver. And -in my case- change django url to use new executable schema

```
from .urls import urlpatterns
with patch('path.to.my_resolver') as mocked_resolver:
    query = QueryType()
    query.set_field(mocked_field, mocked_resolver)
    mocked_resolver.return_value = mocked_return_value
    my_schema = make_executable_schema(my_base_schema, query, snake_case_fallback_resolvers)
    urlpatterns.clear() # remove main urls
    urlpatterns.append(path('graphql/', GraphQLView.as_view(schema=my_schema), name='graphql'))
```

Note: *snake_case_fallback_resolvers* is because of handling *convert_kwargs_to_snake_case* decorator