# How to mock info.context in Django / Graphene tests

Tags: django, graphql, pytest, graphene-python, graphene-django

### Problem

I'm trying to test a graphql query. The query requires that the user associated with the request (`info.context.user`) is a super user (`.is_superuser`). Otherwise it throws an exception. I'm trying to test that the query works properly but am unsure how to ensure that `info.context.user.is_superuser` resolves to true in the test. Please help!

#### schema.py

```py
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    gardens = graphene.List(GardenType)
    
    def resolve_gardens(self, info):
        user = info.context.user
        if not (user.is_superuser or user.is_staff):
            raise Exception("You must be staff or a superuser to view all gardens")
        return Garden.objects.all()
```

#### tests.py

```py
from graphene_django.utils.testing import GraphQLTestCase, graphql_query
from users.models import CustomUser

class TestGraphQLQueries(GraphQLTestCase):
    """
    Test that GraphQL queries related to gardens work and throw errors appropriately
    """

    def test_gardens_query(self):
        response = self.query(
            """
            query {
                gardens {
                    id
                    name
                    owner {
                        id
                        email
                    }
                }
            }
            """
        )

        self.assertResponseNoErrors(response)
```

### Error Thrown

```sh
gardens/tests.py:93: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
../env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/graphene_django/utils/testing.py:114: in assertResponseNoErrors
    self.assertNotIn("errors", list(content.keys()))
E   AssertionError: 'errors' unexpectedly found in ['errors', 'data']
-------------------------- Captured log call ---------------------------
ERROR    graphql.execution.utils:utils.py:155 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dthompson/Code/personal/gardenbuilder-backend/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/promise/promise.py", line 489, in _resolve_from_executor
    executor(resolve, reject)
  File "/home/dthompson/Code/personal/gardenbuilder-backend/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/promise/promise.py", line 756, in executor
    return resolve(f(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/dthompson/Code/personal/gardenbuilder-backend/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/graphql/execution/middleware.py", line 75, in make_it_promise
    return next(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dthompson/Code/personal/gardenbuilder-backend/src/gardens/schema.py", line 43, in resolve_gardens
    raise Exception("You must be a superuser to view all gardens")
graphql.error.located_error.GraphQLLocatedError: You must be a superuser to view all gardens
======================= short test summary info ========================
FAILED gardens/tests.py::TestGraphQLQueries::test_gardens_query - Ass...
```

Comment: Wouldn't sending the request as superuser pass the test?

Comment: Yes, sending the request as superuser would pass the test, but how do I mock that for testing purposes?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot pass in context value directly into self.query method.

What you need to do is create a test client, and then provide the test context value to use for the test.

```
from graphene.test import Client
from snapshottest import TestCase

from users.models import CustomUser
from .schema import schema

class SuperUser:
    is_superuser = True

class TestContext:
    user = SuperUser()

class TestGraphQLQueries(TestCase):
    """
    Test that GraphQL queries related to gardens work and throw errors appropriately
    """

    context_value = TestContext()

    def test_gardens_query(self):
        client = Client(schema, context_value=self.context_value)
        query = (
            """
            query {
                gardens {
                    id
                    name
                    owner {
                        id
                        email
                    }
                }
            }
            """
        )
        
        self.assertMatchSnapshot(client.execute(query))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a graphene request's user in the same way as setting it for Django, by using RequestFactory.  As per my answer in [Testing Graphene-Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45493295/testing-graphene-django/47762174#47762174) the pattern is

```
from django.test import RequestFactory, TestCase
from graphene.test import Client


user = ... (fetch your test superuser)
api_query = """
        query {
            gardens {
                id
                name
                owner {
                    id
                    email
                }
            }
        }
        """
request_factory = RequestFactory()
context_value = request_factory.get('/api/')  # or use reverse() on your API endpoint
context_value.user = user
client = Client(schema)
executed = client.execute(api_query, context_value=context_value)
output_data = executed.get('data')
```